# Searching for a pattern in Ext JS

Tags: regex, extjs, filter, grid, store

I have a grid with certain records and a textfield above it. The textfield is connected with the grid such that each time there is a keyup event it goes to a filter function in order to only show those records that contain the characters that the user typed in. The problem is that right now it only matches from the starting character of the record string name, however id like it to be able to filter all those records that contain the typed in characters anywhere in the record string name.

Screenshots:-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXUCk.jpg

The first image shows the records, second shows the filtered results when i type in 'c', the third shows that when i press in 'p' it doesn't return any result however i want it to return "GPL Products" and "Reporting Period" since they both contain 'p' in them.

Here's the code:-

```
  onDimensionFilterTextBoxKeyUp: function (filterTxtBox, evntObj, eOpts) {
    var dimStore = this.getDimensionStoreStore();
    //get new value
    var searchValue = filterTxtBox.getValue();
    //var regex = /searchValue*/;
    //clear previous search value
    dimStore.clearFilter();
    if (!Ext.isEmpty(searchValue)) {
        //load filtered data 
        dimStore.filter('DimensionName', searchValue);
    }
  }
```

I tried creating a regexp pattern using the /searchValue*/ but using that just breaks the filter and it doesn't return even a single result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
re = new RegExp(searchValue, ignoreCase ? 'i' : '');
store.filter(field, re);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify a case-insensitive search.

```
dimStore.filter('DimensionName', searchValue, true, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that those answers above are old, but maybe can help someone.

`store.filter({
        anyMatch: true,
        exactMatch: false,
        property: valor_property, 
        value: valor
 });`